# How to show a partial view in the DOM, from a data obtained from a select control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on a Net Core 5 MVC project.

I want to generate a warehouse receipt document from a purchase order, the idea is to show the available orders in the "select" control and when clicking the "Cargar OC" button, load and show a preview of the order, after this the user will click on "Crear Entrada" and it will take me to another view to generate the entry.

I have generated the view as a partial view, but my problem is that I don't know how to put the preview of the Purchase Order in the DOM.

For further reference, see the attached image

[image]

this function loads the Purchase Order data and if it returns the Json correctly, this is where I don't know how to take this data and put it in the DOM.

Controller code

```
// GET: DoctosAlmMasterController/GetOrdenCompra
public IActionResult GetOrdenCompra(int id)
{
    if (id != 0)
    {
        VHiloOcMasterViewModel vHiloOCMasterViewModel = Singleton.Instance.EntityManager.GetEntity<VHiloOcMasterViewModel>(id);

        if (vHiloOCMasterViewModel != null)
        {
            /* Obtengo los datos de una Vista MySql */
            List<VHiloOcDetailModel> lstVHiloOcDetail = Singleton.Instance.EntityManager.GetEntitiesByProperties<VHiloOcDetailModel>(nameof(VHiloOcDetailModel.HiloOCId), id);

            List<VHiloOcDetailModel> objDetail = new();

            int i = 0;
            foreach (var item in lstVHiloOcDetail)
            {
                objDetail.Add(new VHiloOcDetailModel());
                objDetail[i].HiloOCId = item.HiloOCId;
                objDetail[i].HiloOCDetId = item.HiloOCDetId;
                objDetail[i].HiloId = item.HiloId;
                objDetail[i].HiloName = item.HiloName;
                objDetail[i].TituloId = item.TituloId;
                objDetail[i].TituloName = item.TituloName;
                objDetail[i].ComposicionHiloId = item.ComposicionHiloId;
                objDetail[i].ComposicionHiloName = item.ComposicionHiloName;
                objDetail[i].TipoHiloId = item.TipoHiloId;
                objDetail[i].TipoHiloName = item.TipoHiloName;
                objDetail[i].SubtipoHiloId = item.SubtipoHiloId;
                objDetail[i].SubtipoHiloName = item.SubtipoHiloName;
                objDetail[i].Cantidad = item.Cantidad;
                objDetail[i].PrecioUnitario = item.PrecioUnitario;
                objDetail[i].ImporteTotal = Convert.ToDouble(item.ImporteTotal);

                i++;
            }
            vHiloOCMasterViewModel.HiloOcDetail = objDetail;
        }

        return View(vHiloOCMasterViewModel);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Javascript code:

```
function getOrdenCompraInfo() {
    let ordenCompraId = $("#OrdenCompraId option:selected").val();

    if (ordenCompraId == "0") {
        Swal.fire({ text: "Seleccione una Órden de Compra.", icon: 'info', allowOutsideClick: false, showConfirmButton: true, timer: 1500, timerProgressBar: true });
        return
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "/DoctosAlmMaster/GetOrdenCompraInfo",
        data: {
            OrdenCompraId: ordenCompraId
        },
        type: "POST",

        success: function (response) {
            //Here I added the view that I received with Json

            /* Mostrar dentro de un contenedor <div> */
            $('#detailsDiv').load("/HiloOcMaster/Details/" + response.hiloOCId);

            /* Mostrar la informacion en una ventana modal */
            //$("#modal-content").load("/HiloOcMaster/Details/" + response.hiloOCId);
            //$("#WinModal").modal("show");
        },

        error: function (errormessage) {
            window.alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the view.

```
<div id="divFrmCreate" class="container-fluid">
    <h5>Entrada de Almacén con Órden de Compra</h5>
    <hr/>
    <form id="frmCreateDocto" class="frmCreateDocto" asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label asp-for="FolioOC" class="control-label"></label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OrdenCompraId, ViewBag.FoliosList as SelectList, new {@class = "form-select"})
                    <span asp-validation-for="OrdenCompraId" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 align-self-end">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-md" onclick="getOrdenCompraInfo();"><i class="fa-regular fa-file-lines"></i> Cargar Orden de Compra</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div id="detailsDiv">
                <!-- ...Here insert content... -->
            </div>
            @*
            <div class="row">
                <div class="container mt-1 mb-2">
                    <!-- Barra de Botones Create Modal Guardar/Limpiar/Regresar -->
                    @*<partial name="~/Views/Shared/Controls/_BtnsCreateNoModal.cshtml"/>*@
            @*        <a id="btnCreate" class="btnCreate btn btn-primary" href="/HiloOcMaster/Create" title="Nueva Orden de Compra"><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i> Crear Entrada</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            *@
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I finally found the solution, I corrected the Javascript function with the solution, thanks to everyone

Comment: Use javascript `fetch` to get a view, that includes the partial view. Use `Html.Partial` to include the view.

Comment: @PoulBak, I checked the documentation of what you tell me, but I don't understand it.

Comment: What does the URL `/DoctosAlmMaster/GetOrdenCompraInfo` display? In other words, when you debug the JavaScript, and have a breakpoint in the `success` function, what is in `data`?

Comment: Well, `$.ajax` is the jQuery version of `fetch`, so that is fine.

Comment: The easiest is to let `"/DoctosAlmMaster/GetOrdenCompraInfo"` return the partial view as html, then you can apply it with jQuery

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I put the "data" parameter too much,
This return Json
consignatarioId: 2
consignatarioName: "xxxxxx"
createdDate: "2022-04-26T14:30:20"
fechaOC: "2022-02-18T00:00:00"
folioOC: "OH000005"
hiloOCId: 5
hiloOcDetail: [{hiloOCId: 5, hiloOCDetId: 7, hiloId: 41, hiloName: "12/1 50/50 POL-ALG OE", tituloId: 1,…}]
observaciones: null
sumaCantidadRecibida: 0
sumaImporteTotal: 0
updateDate: null

Comment: Please add the controller code as well. need to understand what GetOrdenCompraInfo() returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the final version off js function.

```
function getOrdenCompraInfo() {
    let ordenCompraId = $("#OrdenCompraId option:selected").val();
    let consignatarioId = 0, almacenId = 0;
    console.log("Orden de Compra # " + ordenCompraId);
    if (ordenCompraId == "0") {
        Swal.fire({ text: "Seleccione una Órden de Compra.", icon: 'info', allowOutsideClick: false, showConfirmButton: true, timer: 1500, timerProgressBar: true });
        return
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "/DoctosAlmMaster/GetOrdenCompraInfo",
        data: {
            OrdenCompraId: ordenCompraId,
            ConsignatarioId: consignatarioId,
            AlmacenId: almacenId
        },
        type: "POST",

        success: function (response) {
            /* Mostrar dentro de un contenedor <div> */
            $('#detailsDiv').load("/HiloOcMaster/Details/" + response.hiloOCId);

            /* Mostrar la informacion en una ventana modal */
            //$("#modal-content").load("/HiloOcMaster/Details/" + response.hiloOCId);
            //$("#WinModal").modal("show");
        },

        error: function (errormessage) {
            window.alert(errormessage.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```